# difference in methods of declaring two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

There are two methods exists to declare a 2D array in python, 
first one is

```
matrix = [[0.0 for x in range(20)] for x in range(41)]
```

second is,

```
matrix = [[0.0] * 20] * 41
```

The first declaration is working fine, but the second declaration is generating unnecessary references. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean _'How is this possible?'_ ? Do you mean how to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by `generating unnecessary references`?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, the elements of the outer list are themselves lists, that is, mutable objects. In Python mutable objects are assigned (and thus copied) by reference, so all the 41 elements of the outer list are identical and reference the same inner list.

The elements of the inner list are floats, and these (as other immutable objects) are copied by value and behave as expected.

Comment: Python does not have primitive types;  *everything* is an object, including lists, floats, ints, bools, and even functions.  The difference is that floats are [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and therefore cannot be changed.  Lists however are mutable, so any changes will be reflected across all 41 items.